# in-app-billing-v3 how to find if purchased or not after uninstall and install?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I got the in-app-billing-v3 running.
My idea is to remove ads and enable features after an in app purchase. That means I have to set a flag in sharedpreferences if the app has been purchased. After that check in sharedpreferences if purchased. If there is no flag in sharedpreferences then check user account if purchased. 
My question is how and where can I check the user account? 
THX